# Solving the equation in which include sum of digits.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solving the equation $x-2(S(x))^2=0$, where $S(x)$ represent sum of digits of $x$ and $x$ in an natural number.

Try: Here $n\geq 1$ and $10^{n-1} \leq S(x)<10^n$

I did not understand how to go further

Could some help me how to solve it, Thanks

Comment: No, if $x$ is an $n$-digit number, S(x) is at most $9n$.  It's $x$ that's between $10^{n-1}$ and $10^n$.  I would start by trying to get a bound on $x$.  What's the biggest it can be?

Comment: I did not undrrstand why $S(x)\leq 9n$.explain me please

Comment: $x$ has $n$ digits, and each is at most $9$, so the sum is at most $9n$.

Comment: Do you know what I mean when I say $S(x)\equiv x \pmod 9?$

Comment: No i did not understand

Comment: That's fine, we can do without it.

Comment: How can we solve it, please explain me

Comment: Note that $x = 2(S(x))^2$.  So if the last digit $S(x)$ is $1,4,6,9$ then the last digit of $2S(x)^2 =2$.If the last digit of $S(x)$ is $2,3,7,8$ then the last digit of $2S(x)^2=8$.  If the last digit of $S(x)$ is $0,5$ then the last digit of $2S(x)^2 = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $x$ has $n$ digits. We know $$
10^{n-1}\le x=2S^2(x)<=2(9n)^2=162n^2
$$
How big can $n$ be?  If $n=4,$ we must have $10^3=1000\le 162\cdot 16=2592,$ which is true.  If $n=5$ we must have $10^4=10,000\le 162\cdot 25=4050,$ which is false.  So, we must have $n\le 4$.

Since $x$ has at most $4$ digits, $S(x)\le 36\implies x=2S^2(x) \le 2592.$

So, we only have to check the values of $x$ up to $2592.$ But we don't have to check all of these.  We know that a solution must be of the form $2k^2$ for $k=1,2,\dots,36,$ so there are only 36 numbers to check.

It is possible to cut this down even further using modular arithmetic, which you haven't studied yet, but $36$ numbers is quite doable even with pencil and paper.

I leave the checking to you.

**EDIT** In response to the OP's comment, I'll give an example.  Say $x=7345$.  Then $$
x= 7000+300+40+5=7(999+1)+3(99+1)+4(9+1)+5 =\\
7\cdot 999 + 3\cdot 99 + 4\cdot 9 + 7+3+4+5 = 9k+S(x)
$$
Since $10^n$ is always one more than a multiple of $9$ this works no matter how many digits $x$ has.

You can use this fact to cut down the numbers that need to be checked.  Since $x$ and $S(x)$ are congruent modulo $9$ we have that $x$ and $2x^2$ are congruent modulo $9$.  You can check that this only happens when $x$ is divisible by $9$, or $x$ leaves a remainder of $5$ when divided by $9$.
So which numbers $2k^2$ in our list  are divisible by $9$?  Those where $k$ is a multiple of $3$.  Which ones leave a remainder of $5$?  Again, you can check that $k$ must leave a remainder of $5$ also. That is, we have to check the numbers $2k^2$ for $k=3,6,9,\dots,36$ and for $k=5,14,23,32$-- $16$ numbers instead of $36.$  I can't think how to cut it down any further without testing the numbers, but the amount of work left is so small it isn't worth bothering with.

Comment: Thanks saulspatz. Although i have a little knowledge of modular arithmetic. Please also  explain how $S(x)=x+9k$